# ERC20 token transfer attempt resulting in underpriced (price change attempted)

Tags: web3js, erc-20, javascript, ethereumjs

It's almost an exact copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019666) but when I ran it, I get the following error message.

> (node:5189) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error:
> transaction underpriced

Below is the code I ran.

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var Web3 = require('web3')
const { ethers } = require('ethers')

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc"))
let mnemonic = "word word word....";
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
eth_privatekey = wallet.privateKey;
const tokenAddress = "0xe66BC94A29A01ea0E897C1bAFe0625C5dA31BC58" 
//SHITTKN CONTRACT ADDRESS(deployed by me)

// set token source, destination and amount
var myAddress =  wallet.address
var toAddress = "0x22b2b66191390738e861D25E987FAB2554060bf6"
var amount = web3.utils.toHex(1.2e18)      // <1.2 token i think

// get transaction count, later will used as nonce
var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress);  

// set your private key here, we'll sign the transaction below
var privateKey = new Buffer.from( eth_privatekey.substring(2), 'hex')  

// Get abi array here https://etherscan.io/address/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0#code

var abiArray = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"stop","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"owner_","type":"address"}],"name":"setOwner","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint128"}],"name":"push","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"name_","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"setName","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"wad","type":"uint128"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"stopped","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"authority_","type":"address"}],"name":"setAuthority","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint128"}],"name":"pull","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"wad","type":"uint128"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"start","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"authority","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"guy","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"symbol_","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":true,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"sig","type":"bytes4"},{"indexed":true,"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"foo","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"name":"bar","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"fax","type":"bytes"}],"name":"LogNote","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"authority","type":"address"}],"name":"LogSetAuthority","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"LogSetOwner","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]

var contractAddress = tokenAddress
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, {from: myAddress})

var rawTransaction = {"from":myAddress, "gasPrice":web3.utils.toHex(2 * 1e9),
"gasLimit":web3.utils.toHex(210000),"to":contractAddress,"value":"0x0",
"data":contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).encodeABI(),"nonce":web3.utils.toHex(count)} 
var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction)

transaction.sign(privateKey)
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))

// check the balance
contract.methods.balanceOf(myAddress).call().then(function(balance){console.log(balance)})
```

I have also tried the following to play with the once

```
var nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress, 'pending');
console.log(nonce)
count = nonce + 1;
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions interacting with the network return promises. You must wrap everything in an async function and await them.

E.g.

```js
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var Web3 = require('web3');
const {ethers} = require('ethers');

(async () => {

    ...

    // get transaction count, later will used as nonce
    var count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress);  

    ...

    await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))

    // check the balance
    await contract.methods.balanceOf(myAddress).call().then(function(balance){console.log(balance)})

})();
```