# ERC20 transaction underpriced

Tags: web3js, transactions, erc-20, sendrawtransaction

I am trying to transfer an ERC20 Token with the following code which is basically taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180941/send-erc20-token-with-web3/50019666#50019666). Running it causes the following Error message:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: transaction underpriced`

Here is my Code:

```
async function transfer(){
    const  Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const Web3 = require("web3");
    const web3 = new Web3("https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/");

    var myAddress = "0x002F5e7f3719E83a93BfD35C9B99e49c647dF673";
    var destAddress = "0xe76dd068d67254D16EE1609C9bF29B21a1c6A7D1";
    var transferAmount = 100;

    var count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress);

    var contractJSON  = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/MyToken.json', 'utf-8'));
    var contractAddress = "0x66A1cAF7811FF42E8ddB46186d22027e8ac002a0";
    var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractJSON.abi, contractAddress, { from: myAddress });

    var requiredGas = await contract.methods.transfer(destAddress, transferAmount).estimateGas({from: myAddress});
    console.log(requiredGas);

    var rawTransaction = {
        "from": myAddress,
        "gas": web3.utils.toHex(requiredGas),
        "gasLimit":web3.utils.toHex(210000),
        "value": 0x0,
        "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(count),
        "to": contractAddress,
        "data": contract.methods.transfer(destAddress, transferAmount).encodeABI(),
        "chainId": 0x61
    };

    var privKey = new Buffer(PRIVATE_KEY, 'hex');
    var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
    tx.sign(privKey);
    var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));
```

I found a similiar problem here [ERC20 token transfer attempt resulting in underpriced (price change attempted)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96702/erc20-token-transfer-attempt-resulting-in-underpriced-price-change-attempted) the solution was to wrap it into an async function which I did aswell. Also I have no pending transaction which apparently causes this error too. Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1):

You're using your probably intended to be gas limit in the place of your gas price. In the place of `gas`, you should use something like `web3.eth.getBlock('latest').minimumGasPrice` to get the gas price, and place the `requiredGas` in the place of `gasLimit`.

Comment: Sadly this also seems to throw the same Error "transaction underpriced"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using BSC and their gas price is about 5 Gwei in a [Sample Transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x10ebebe287c06327ce69a3e84f292c3b4c1bd63db596fb38c1d259b327b1e675). How about adding
`gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(5000000000)` into your `rawTransaction`?
Also I don't think fixed "gasLimit" to `210000` is a good practice, it should be higher than `requiredGas`, and I think it's the same as `gas` field in web3 lib. So I suggest:

```js
var rawTransaction = {
        "from": myAddress,
        "gas": web3.utils.toHex(requiredGas*2),
        "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(requiredGas*2),
        "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(5000000000),
        "value": 0x0,
        "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(count),
        "to": contractAddress,
        "data": contract.methods.transfer(destAddress, transferAmount).encodeABI(),
        "chainId": 0x61
    };
```

`ethereumjs-tx` accepts `gasLimit` as tx params while web3.js accepts `gas` with the same meaning. So I guess we can try both params